# Getting a large amount of data with traceview

Tags: android, buffer, buffer-overflow, android-traceview

I'm running some benchmarks and some overflow the traceview buffer, I'm already using the max buffer size that I can (400MB). 
How can I get these data? (I need the hole benchmark to be traced, not only some smaller portions of the benchmark, each one in a different file)

Is it possible to flush the buffer to a file when it is full?

Is it possible to write everything directly in a file, instead of just when the trace stops?

any other alternative?

Comment: How are you setting up the trace? Using the methods on `Debug`, or via DDMS?

Comment: via Debug with the max buffer size I can set.

Comment: I suspect that you're out of luck, but that is just a guess. I recommend that you use coarser tests (e.g., `Log` calls) to narrow down the scope of your trace to something more manageable.